# ios safari location permission prompt pops up after allowed for website

Tags: ios, location, mobile-safari

is there an automatic reset of approved location permissions for mobile safari in iOS? what i am experiencing is that for the React webapp I'm developing which requires gps location is that every now and then I receive the prompt to allow location permissions for safari and a 2nd prompt to allow locations for my webapp. Should safari save the approved permission until i reset the ios or clear safari cache.